# how to implement a websocket server with node.js?

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, websocket

are there any examples? And how node.js communicates with traditional php scripts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you should read the (now deprecated) [Specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76).

For a straight forward implementation you can take a look at my code here:
https://github.com/BonsaiDen/NodeGame-Shooter/blob/master/server/nodegame/ws.js

If you like to have a big wall of abstraction with a trillion fall backs, take a look at: http://socket.io/

#### BUT...

Keep in mind when building your own one, the WebSocket protocol is about to change due to recently discovered security vulnerabilities:
http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/12/websockets-disabled-in-firefox-4/
http://blog.pusherapp.com/2010/12/9/it-s-not-websockets-it-s-your-broken-proxy

As for the PHP part, it's unclear to me what you exactly want to do you should give us more information about that.

Comment: +1. After the Barth paper, WebSocket is in even more of a state of flux than normal. It's going to be a while before there's anything stable and usable. You can of course use Flash sockets in the meantime (with all the caveats that involves).

Comment: @bobince Don't remind me of those Flash Sockets... UTF8 + Flash Sockets = Nightmare :(

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at socket.io. This includes a client and a server-side library.

http://socket.io

Comment: do you know if we can just use the client side of this socket.io and construct the server backend with php?

Comment: @Ege Özcan If you copy the Node.js Code 1:1 that should be possible, but keep in mind that the PHP process has to run all the time in order for the WebSockets to work, so if you have a limit for the requests lifetime it obviously won't work.